# In Jquery what is the best way to calculate a fee based on percentage of an input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script making that is going to be a worksheet for debt counselors. On the worksheet are input fields that collect different types of debts, like credit cards and mortgages, which are summed up into a variable called `subTotal`. I also have an input field that will be set as the variable `percent`. This input field is an adjustable number between 5 and 30 that is going to represent a percent.

I am trying to figure out the best way to take these variables and make a fee calculation. The result should be the percent of the subtotal. So for example if the `var subTotal` sums a total of `200` and somebody enters `15` into the input field that is represented by the variable `percent` . The calculation should be `30`

Here are the variables

```
var subTotal = self.calculateTotalFor(elems);
// this the summed total for the debt input fields

var percent = $("#percent_field")
//I'm not sure if this is the best way to set this value because it needs to be a percent
```

Then I need to take those variables and get a fee calculation, but I know this method won't work because it does not add a `decimal` in front of the `percent` value.

```
total += (percent - 1) * subTotal;
```

Any ideas will be helpful as I am just a novice, thanks.

Comment: `percent = +percent / 100` would convert that `15` into `0.15` and store it in the variable `percent`. Of course, you might need to do more checking on the value returned from `$("#percent_field")` than that, unless you can ensure your users won't input anything but valid numbers.

Comment: use `var percent = $("#percent_field").val()`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5z86/

Comment: @crush thanks, I will add validation into the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var subTotal = self.calculateTotalFor(elems);
var percent = $("#percent_field").val(); // <------ The value....
var total = percent * subTotal / 100;
```